# Hibernate custom proxy generator - Stop equals() from initializing a lazy proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy, javassist

I have entity classes and these entity classes implement their own equals() function, which just compares the Ids of the classes. Sadly, invoking equals() on a Hibernate proxy initializes it, which is completly useless in my case.

I use javassist as a proxy provider. Is there a way to modify the proxy generation code to not load the entity during an equals call, but instead does something else for me? Can I plug a custom proxy provider in Hibernate?

<sup>Please do not start a discussion on how equals should behave in Hibernate, this goes to far, there are different opinions on the topic, which I already know, and is not part of the question :).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you override classes in the hibernate.jar, and providing your own Implementation of BasicLazyInitializer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly did you do to solve this problem, or point to any sort of howto manual? Thanks.

Comment: I added some more branches to the invoke function, to do something special in case of the equals funtion (and some other here not relevant functions). Oh, and I have a modified copy of the BasicLazyInitializer class on my classpath. The style might be bad, but the outcome was worth it :).